# How to write JUnit Test for a custom validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, junit

My Custom Validation annotation looks like this:

```java
@ConstraintComposition(AND)
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z]{4}", message = "Invalid")
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface ValidChars {
```

Since I don't have any class in the validatedBy section, I am not sure how to write unit test for this annotation.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a JUnit test for a class that uses your `ValidChars` interface. However, as `validatedBy` is empty, it means that there is no validation implementation class that is associated with your constraint annotation.

So your test will be to verify that the constraint annotation is being applied correctly to some class, but you won't be able to test the "actual" validation logic.

In your test case, you can make use of the Bean Validation API (`javax.validation.*`). You can use `validate` of `Validator`, it'll check if the constraints specified in your `ValidChars` are being satisfied by the instance being validated.

The test then just asserts any constraint violation in the validation result..

e.g.

```java
// YourEntity.java
private class YourEntity
{

    @ValidChars
    String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```java
// YourEntityTest.java
@Test
void testInvalidCharsShouldContainViolations()
{
    // given
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    YourEntity yourEntity = new YourEntity();
        
    // when
    yourEntity.setName( "some-invalid-input" );

    // then
    Set<ConstraintViolation<YourEntity>> violations = validator.validate( yourEntity );
    assertFalse( violations.isEmpty() );
}
```